# working hours and negative time

Tags: date-and-time

I have a list of `TimeObjects`.

I want to subtract 5h from each element and if `TimeObject < 5h` then give a negative hour.

My goal is to count the amount of time that I’ve worked last month.
To doing that I have a list of the amount time worked each day so that `{{13/9,7:00}...}`
I make with that a list of `DateValue` to that I have to subtract 5h to each element to know only the extra time that i’ve worked.

How could I do this?

Edited.

Comment: Can't you just compute `times - TimeObject[{5, 0, 0}]`?  That's what [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeObject.html) seems to imply.  `Count[..., _?Negative]` or `Count[..., _?Positive]` etc. to count a particular type of result.

Comment: I have corrected my answer according to the format you provided. Please  accept it by selecting the tick mark if it answered your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your working hours are stored in the list `time` according to the format you provided, then your total overtime can be calculated like this

```
time = {{"13/9", "7:00"}, {"14/9", "3:30"}};
overtime = TimeObject@DateList@{#[[2]], {"Hour", ":", "Minute"}} - 
 TimeObject@DateList@{"5:00", {"Hour", ":", "Minute"}} & /@ time;
Total@overtime
```

Comment: Why does ‘TimeObject’ subtraction shows in minutes?